# How to pass a combined command as a parameter to a function

Tags: linux, shell

```
checkcommand() {
   $1
}

checkcommand "which git || apt install git"
```

it will fail. How can I make it work and get the output?

Comment: [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) has more-than-passing relevance.

Comment: Re `which`, also see [How to check if a program exists from a Bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592620/608639). You should use `command -v`, not `which`. `command -v` takes aliases and paths into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to wrap the string in `eval` keyword

```
checkcommand() {
  eval "$1"
}
```

Quoting it (`"$1"`, not `$1`) ensures that the exact string is evaluated as code; otherwise, it gets split into words, each word is expanded as a glob, and the resulting words are concatenated back together; if you're lucky, this didn't change the meaning of your command -- but one may not always be lucky, so it's always best to quote your expansions unless you explicitly know *why* you're leaving them unquoted in any contrary case.

See the man page for POSIX [`eval`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1posix/eval/).

Comment: would this work if the commands (& args) contained embedded spaces?

Comment: @DarrenSmith, it works if the command's literal contents are able to be successfully parsed as bash code, whether or not spaces are present.

Comment: its worth remembering there are dangers with eval:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead

Comment: Yup -- it should only be used with a hardcoded string hand-vetted to be safely parsed as code. In the OP's use case here, they *do* provide precisely that. BTW, I'd suggest [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) as an ideal such warning.

Comment: @DarrenSmith, ...btw, I edited this answer with an explanation of why the quoting is necessary -- does that help wrt. the question about how spaces &c. are handled?

Comment: @Charles, yes I think its good to bring attention to this aspect of the solution.

Comment: thanks! Actually, the problem is more complex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58740831/how-to-pass-a-nested-command-to-function-in-a-command-line-to-ssh

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to run a single string as if it were a command -- pass an explicit *argument list* instead. That gives you the flexibility of picking whichever usage mode works for you:

```
## first, define your function as:
checkcommand() {
   "$@"   # expands to "$1" "$2" "$3" ...etc, for all arguments that actually exist
}

## then, you can pass it any simple command...
type git || checkcommand apt install git

## ...or you can use it with eval...
checkcommand eval "type git || apt install git"

## ...or you can pass it a function with an argument list...
installPkg() { for pkg; do type "$pkg" || apt install "$pkg"; done; }
checkcommand installPkg git tig gcc

## ...or you can tell it to invoke a whole new shell instance...
checkcommand sh -c 'type git || apt install git'
```

For a detailed description of why treating a string as if it were a command is doomed to fail (in sufficiently complex use cases), see [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: my concern with this is it leads to noisy string quoting, e.g.  if I want to run & check `echo "two   spaces"` (assume two spaces between these words) , I'd have to escape the quote chars:  `checkcommand  eval "echo \"two  spaces\""`  ... this gets messy

Comment: It's only the `eval` option (of the three choices that using `"$@"` enables) that requires any such quoting. Just `checkcommand echo "two  spaces"` works fine. And `checkcommand eval 'echo "two  spaces"'`, of course, is a lower-overhead eval-based option (with [all of `eval`'s usual caveats](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)).

Comment: okay, nice one of the alternative works without soucre code adornments, but I think there is a lot to mentally manage here, e.g., when to use eval, how to deal with spaces  etc.

Comment: "One"? I'd argue that there aren't any "adornments" in the function case either; it's only `eval` that's a general bad idea (but necessary if we want shell syntax to be used, which the OP explicitly asked for).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest an alternative approach, I acknowledge doesn't answer directly.

I suggest this approach because it can be complex to pass command & args and aggregated groups of commands & args to another function to be executing and checked.

Instead a simpler approach is execute your commands and then run a check function after that, e.g.

```
check_error()
{
    lasterr=$?
    msg="$*"

    if [ "${lasterr}X" != "0X" ];
    then
        echo "command failed, errcode ${lasterr}, $msg"
        exit 1
    fi
}

...

which git || apt install git
check_error "git failed"
```

... note that `check_error` function must be the next statement **immediately** after the commands you wish to check.

Comment: The `"${foo}X"` hack is only needed for ancient, 1970s-vintage shells. There hasn't been any reason to use it whatsoever since at least the early 90s, so long as deprecated constructs like using `-a` and `-o` to build compound test commands are avoided. (See the `OB` obsolescence markers in the [POSIX `test` standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)).

Comment: The whole `$?` test is unnecessary if we only use the function following a failed command (i.e. `which git || apt install git || check_error "git failed"`).

Comment: @Toby: that's an acceptable alternative solution, although I think its more intrusive to the code being checked.  As example, I typically copy paste commands from vim into terminal, and so having the shell commands appear unadorned in the source file is helpful then.    Also danger of the `|| check` accidentally finding its way into an if condition (by unsuspecting user).

Comment: @Charles,  hack or not,  I see this approach (using `test`) in plenty of contemporary low level scripts., e.g., just about every configure script I have ever opened.  It's pretty simple and robust.

Comment: `configure` is built by autoconf, which intentionally is compatible with 1970s shells. That's why configure scripts also test whether your shell treats `^` as a pipe character. No shell made in the last four decades (except for [the Heirloom project's Bourne implementation](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/), a project which exists specifically to have a version of 1970s-era UNIX tools that build on modern systems) has actually done that, though.

Comment: (one exception to the above claim -- SunOS was shipping pre-POSIX Bourne into the 2000s -- it was finally killed for good in Solaris 11 -- but even then, they *also* shipped a POSIX-compliant `sh` as well. And even Sun's non-POSIX `sh`, and the Heirloom one derived from it, don't need the `"x${foo}"`/`"${foo}x"` hack).

Comment: ...keep in mind that autoconf goes a long way back -- it already existed before the first release of automake in 1994. That was 25 years ago; needing to be paranoid about systems with 10-year-old shells then was different from being paranoid about systems with 30-year-old shells today. I'd call only one of those two paranoias justifiable.