# How to pass a nested command to function in a command line to ssh?

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER=127.0.0.1
ssh root@$SERVER << EOF
   checkcommand(){
      echo "checking $1"
      command -v $1 || apt install $1
   }
   checkcommand git
EOF
```

It won't work at all. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the variables in the here-document from being evaluated on the local system. You can make it act like a quoted string by putting the end token in quotes.

```
#!/bin/bash
SERVER=127.0.0.1
ssh root@$SERVER << 'EOF'
   checkcommand(){
      echo "checking $1"
      command -v $1 || apt install $1
   }
   checkcommand git
EOF
```

This is documented in the Bash Manual section on [Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Documents):

> If any part of *word* is quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on *word*, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded. If *word* is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence `\newline` is ignored, and `‘\’` must be used to quote the characters `‘\’`, `‘$’`, and `‘`’`.

*word* refers to the token after `<<`, and *delimiter* refers to the matching token at the end of the here-doc.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I never see the difference here. Is there any reference for such subtle syntax?

Comment: I've added the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as follow:

```
ssh root@server command -v git || apt install git
```

Comment: This executes `apt install git` on the local system, not the remote server.

Comment: In my test, the git command exists, so, I forced and, really, the or statement runned the command locally. In a new try, i isolated the command 
    `ssh root@server 'command -v git || apt install git'` and worked fine, but, your answer responds directly what @D-C wants, maintaining the original code working.

Comment: The whole point of the script is to install `git` on the remote system, not the local system.

Comment: I also suspect the posted code is a simplification, and it wants to install other programs, not just `git`.